# quickfix initiator does not replay message on resend request

Tags: c++, quickfix

i am working on a quickfix/c++ initiator and this initiator passed certification without
one exeception: The resend request is not treated as the backend expects.
They like to have a message replay in response to resend request, where my client only does a squence reset.

I thought the quickfix handles this message correctly. I get this request from
server backend, but don't know what to do.

The server backend expects me to re-send all messages with seq# in 
in range defined by tag 7 and 16, for instance: 
      7=2 16=14

How can i do this, or why this does not happen automatically.
Many thanks.

Comment: It seems PersistMessages need to be set to Y

Comment: Did that solve your problem?  If so, you can post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.